# Mac Terminal Foreign Host-Name

Tags: security, terminal.app

When I was recently connected to a coffee shop wireless network using Terminal for some coding I saw a foreign "preface" (if that is the right word) before my username. Rather than

Normal_Name:~ bhorowitz$

I saw

roberts-iphone:~ bhorowitz$

although it still seemed I was connected to my normal system with nothing else seeming strange. I don't recognize "roberts-iphone" at all. When I logged off of the wireless network it reverted back to "Normal_Name"

Is this some sort of security vulnerability? What caused this direct connection?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about why or how it was changed, but it seems like you can overwrite this pretty easily by typing this into your `~/.profile` by using the environment variable `PS1='hostname'`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804397/change-in-the-hostname-user-in-terminal-in-leopard-osx)